# Unwanted margin in UL

Tags: html, css, layout

Why is there a margin in the ul?  The navbar goes directly below and out of the header when I float left or right.  If I remove Ul it doesnt drop below.  I dont understand it.  How do I fix it?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
   <div id="container">
       <div id="header">
           <div class="navbar">
               <ul>
               <li><a href="#"></a>NAV1</li>
               <li><a href="#"></a>NAV2</li>
               <li><a href="#"></a>NAV3</li>
               </ul>
           </div>
       </div>

   </div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
html{
    height:100%;
}
body{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background-color: grey;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#container{
    width:80%;
    margin:auto;
}
#header{
    width:100%;
}
.navbar{
    width:100%;

}
ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:25%;
    float:left
}
li{
    display:inline;
}
```

Comment: the only margin that the ul has is inherited from the #container

Comment: Put a border on it! You can use this to try and explain your question a bit more: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/0mban3xr/

Answer (score 1):

There is no margin on the UL, it just appears that way as it is inside your container, which has `margin: auto` on it, which centers the #container element on your page and has 80% width.

Move your nav outside of the container if you want it to float to the left of the body, or use:

```
position: absolute;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
```

instead of floating it and it will go to the left of the nearest relative container (in this case the body as nothing is set with `position: relative`.

EDIT: Also, your links are not structured correctly:

`<li><a href="#"></a>NAV1</li>`

Should be: `<li><a href="#">NAV1</a></li>` if you want NAV1 to be the text of the link

Comment: "nearest relative container (in this case the body..." => in this case the [Initial Containing Block](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#x1) which is a couple of containers up from the body.

Answer (score 0):

It's not about margin,because there is no margin, there is not enough space of ul. Im not sure what do you want to achieve but u can remove `width: 25%;` from ul.

Comment: Why is there not enough space of ul?I'm trying to have the container, header and navbar divs wrap around the li selector. and then float it to the left or right.  Any idea how?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

```css
html{
    height:100%;
}
body{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background-color: grey;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#container{
    width:80%;
    margin:auto;
}
#header{
    width:100%;
}
.navbar{
    width:100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
}
li{
    display:inline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
   <div id="container">
       <div id="header">
           <div class="navbar">
               <ul>
               <li><a href="#"></a>NAV1</li>
               <li><a href="#"></a>NAV2</li>
               <li><a href="#"></a>NAV3</li>
               </ul>
           </div>
       </div>

   </div>

</body>
</html>
```